# Where is the ambiguity in this grammar?

Tags: formal-grammars, ambiguity

I am trying to understand ambiguous grammar in programming languages. I was given this ruleset and told it was ambiguous. If my understanding is correct, this means that it is possible to create the same sentence using different parse trees. After looking at it for a while, I can't find the sentence/parse trees that show the ambiguity.

s ::= a

a ::= a a | A | B | C

Comment: Your understanding of ambiguity meaning that you can create different abstract syntax trees to represent them is correct. What have you tried? You need to show some work.

Comment: Hint: consider the string "AAA".

Answer (score 1):

More a tip than an answer, but it should get you to the solution:

Try to produce a word with 3 terminal symbols. Can you find more than one syntax tree for the same word?

Comment: So, i think this is more a comment than an answer.. :)